# wamp installation can t get myadmin running

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I recently installed wampserver3.1.4_x64 w/o prior PHP or any wamp install.

system config is Windows 7 64 bits.

when I try to access myphpmyadmin from the main localhost server page it throws an error complaining about mysqli suggesting to read some documentation (which I did)
The error message is the following (in french)

> "Il manque l'extension mysqli. Merci de vérifier la configuration PHP. Voir la documentation pour plus de détails."

which can be translated to

> "extension mysqli  is missing. Thank you for checking the PHP configuration. See the documentation for more details."**

The documentation points to 
[this](http://localhost/phpmyadmin/doc/html/faq.html#faqmysql).

I did verify from the WAMPServer / PHP / extension icon system tray that mysqli the extension is checked.

With phpinfo in Loaded configuration (use `http://localhost/?phpinfo=1`)
I checked which ini file is used. 
Actually Loaded Configuration File is set to : `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.35\bin\php.ini`

The file `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.35\bin\php.ini`  is a **symlik** pointing to  `c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.10/phpForApache.ini`

From `c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.10` I can open `phpForApache.ini`. 
In this file I can verify that **extension_dir** is set to `c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.10/ext/` and **mysqli** extension defined (no `;` character at the beginning of the line).

The path is valid and a dll named **php_mysqli.dll** can be found in that directory.

Any advice ?

Comment: Hi, Did you install all the MSVC Runtime libraries as specified in the first dialog of the install script?

Answer (score 0):

for some reasons (unexplained) it worked this morning. It appears the installation took place in the middle of a windows update.